# Что использовать место deprecated createJsonGenerator в Jackson API?

Tags: java, jackson

Надо найти альтернативу но гугл не помогает.  Есть идеи?

Answer (score 1):

Да, есть: просто заходишь в [документацию](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory.html) и видишь

> Since 2.2, use createGenerator() instead.

Кстати, по запросу "createJsonGenerator deprecated" это первая же ссылка в Google.